# Determine whether input date range overlaps with existing ones

Tags: django, algorithm, date, python-3.x, language-agnostic

I have a table in database which stores `items` that can be rented for a period of few days.

Now whenever someone rents an `item`, they specify a `start_date` and an `end_date`(basically a `date range` for which they want to rent that `item`).

I want to know what is the efficient algorithm (in terms of time complexity) to check that input `date range` doesn't overlap with existing `date ranges` in the database.

**Illustration:**

```
|<------existing 1------->|
                                    |<------existing 2------->|
               |<------ input date range ---->| (which clearly, overlaps)
```

**Note:**

This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) question. That one checks whether two `date ranges` overlap. My question is about an input `date range` overlapping with multiple existing `date ranges`

**Another Note:**

In case you are confused by this question's tags, I am open to both kind of answers, `language-agnostic` as well as `language-specific`.

For those who want to give `language-specific` answer, here are more details:

I have a `django 1.9` project running on `python 3.4` with `PostgreSQL` as database. My models are:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BookingPeriod(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that all previous input is legal. In case not, it can be altered to fit other scenarios.

Keep two ordered lists in your system - one for the `start date`s and one for the `end date`s. These list will obviously need to have a way to find the correlating item in the other list.
When receiving a new input, find the largest `start date` that is smaller than the new inputs' `start date` and check that the relevant `end date` is also smaller than the new `start date`, otherwise the new input is illegal.

Same goes for the `end date`, just the other way round.

I think this can be done (using trees instead of lists) in `O(log n)`.

Comment: your answer looks very promising, can you please give at least some hint on how this can be done using trees?

Comment: Sure. Instead of using an ordered list, use a tree. The AVL, black-red or 2-3 trees all promise  `O(log n)` performance for these actions...

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that achieves this result:

```
def validate_overlap(periods, count_days=True):
    """
    Receives a list with DateRange or DateTimeRange and returns True
    if periods overlap.
    In this application it is guaranteed that the end of each period is
    not inclusive. Therefore if a period ends in 15/5 and another starts
    in 15/5, they do not overlap. The same with datetime periods.
    """
    periods.sort()
    no_overlap = [True]
    for each in range(0, len(periods) - 1):
        latest_start = max(periods[each].lower, periods[each + 1].lower)
        earliest_end = min(periods[each].upper, periods[each + 1].upper)
        delta = earliest_end - latest_start
        if count_days:
            no_overlap.append(max(0, delta.days) == 0)
        else:
            no_overlap.append(max(0, delta.total_seconds()) == 0)
    return False if all(no_overlap) else True
```